# Rowversion field causes BULK INSERT to only import every other row

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, rowversion

When I perform a BULK INSERT into a table with a rowversion field, only every other row gets imported.

Here's my source text file:

[image]

If I perform a BULK INSERT into a table with a rowversion field, only two rows are imported:

[image]

However, if I do the exact same thing but comment out the rowversion field, all four rows are imported:

[image]

Is this a bug in SQL Server?  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a way to BULK INSERT into tables with rowversion columns?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's choking on the fact that the number of columns between source and destination doesn't match up (yes, even though you cannot supply an actual value for a `ROWVERSION` column). Consider using `INSERT ... SELECT FROM OPENROWSET(BULK, ...)` instead so you have more flexibility in the columns and their order.

Comment: Thanks, @JeroenMostert.  It looks like that approach would also require defining a format file to specify field and row terminators.  I think for now I'm going to go with the temporary view approach.  If that doesn't work out, I will circle back to this idea.

Comment: To be honest, as soon as you run into any even slightly non-trivial scenario with bulk importing, it starts paying off to use client code to do it (e.g. .NET and `SqlBulkCopy`, `bcp` but with some pre-processing step (like autogenerating the format based on DB queries), or the horror that is SSIS if you absolutely must). The built-in bulk import functionality is extremely narrow-minded and inflexible on the input side in its pursuit of speed on the output side. It's also an absolute beast to troubleshoot, as you've experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I found one [workaround](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d8d5fbe4-a0bd-44b2-b6d4-3d912c8ed180/how-to-bulk-insert-data-to-table-with-timestamp-column#85fd3211-40d3-4bde-8d9c-dd0c43d16e41), but it will require creating and dropping a view to do the bulk insert.  It's not a huge deal in my case, since I'm automating the whole process anyway, but I'd still like to know if there is some way to better deal with this without having to create a temporary database object to do it.

[image]